# Configure a VPN with google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

at the moment I am trying to create a vpn for the company where I work, we have two instances, what is needed in the company is to create a tunnel, to be able to access from home or from the office, using our personal pc , I read a couple of articles and I was reading the documentation that is as support in the official page, but I can not make the configuration, I hope they can help me or tell me how I can contact by a means for technical support ?, I hope I'm sorry For my English, I do not really master it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google provides cloud VPN which uses IPSEC to create a gateway-to-gateway VPN tunnel. This would work well if you just had to connect from the office.

If you are a looking to access your instances from both home and office. (i.e) a client-to-gateway (road warrior) scenario. You would need to provision another dedicated VPN instance in the cloud. If that's something you are prepared to do, there are many open source VPN solutions that you can install.

OpenVPN is one of the popular ones. It has a community version that's free and a little harder to setup. 
https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html

They also provide an enterprise version which is free up to 2 concurrent users. 
https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html

The documentation should get you started.

Next time just post on ServerFault as these questions are not relevant here.

Comment: Understood, but I only have the doubt, the openvpn software, has to be installed on client machines or instances? , Excuse my ignorance, I'm really new to these things

Comment: I don't think you would want to install them on your instances. If they are being used for something else.

You would have to provision a new instance and then install Open VPN 
 server on it in the cloud. 

You would also have to install openvpn client on your client machines.

Comment: Ok, then I would have to create a new instance and in it, install the vpn service, such as Open Vpn? , I imagine that from that instance I would configure access to my two instances ,?

Comment: Yep. And you would make this new machine internet facing and open the desired ports so that you can use the client to VPN.

Comment: I already install my vpn service, configure a user but when I try to access this error is displayed;
<img src = "http://imgur.com/ZLlzg19">

I also have my firewall rules which are as follows:
<img src = "http://imgur.com/xd6d4kP">
I have to open ports, and I have to create a route to my machine, this is the route:

Net
Default
Address range of the IP address
104.197.181.0/24
Priority
1
Instance Tags
This path applies to all instances
Next jump
Windows-2012-r2 (us-central1-a zone)

I hope you can guide me more than you have already helped me, since I still can not solve this

Comment: Create a new question on server fault.